# How to apply better Python solver to solve a function

Tags: python, dataframe

I have tried to find/ apply the python Solver (SciPy/SymPy) but I'm not sure how to apply it properly.

The objective is that I would like to find the better solver solution for the **optimal Coupon Rate** that would yield the **IRR** equals to **Risk Free rate**

The function `EIRRCal` is to return a `coupon rate` (not an optimal one),`IRR`, and `diff` a difference between IRR and Risk Free rate.

I tried and used the `linspace` function to determine the range of possible outcomes of the functions as shown below (only a part of whole codes):

```
def optimalCoupon(recovery_rate,marginal_pd_rate,iteration):

    coupons = np.linspace(0.001,0.300,iteration)
    amat = []
    bmat = []
    cmat = []

    x = recovery_rate
    y = marginal_pd_rate

    for coupon in coupons:
        a_coupon, a_eirr, a_diff = EIRRCal(coupon, period, x, y)

        amat.append(a_coupon)
        bmat.append(a_eirr)
        cmat.append(abs(a_diff))

    for index, value in enumerate(cmat):
        if value == min(cmat):
            lowest_index = index
            optimal_coupon = amat[lowest_index]



    b_coupon, b_eirr, b_diff = EIRRCal(optimal_coupon, period, x, y)

    return [b_coupon, b_eirr, b_diff]
```

However, it took quite long process time (around 7 minutes for only 500 rows of dataframe and iterations=1000]

Comment: If it possible for you to rewrite `EIRRCal` to use arrays as its arguments and to return array values too, you _should_ get a good speed up.

Comment: Thank you **gboffi**, not sure whether I got your point, but the `EIRRCal` is already a function that calculation the expected IRR that combined arrays of defaulted cash flows and non-defaulted cash flows.

Comment: What happens if you write `a, b, c = EIRRCal(coupons, period, x, y)`? [Note it's `coupons` and not `coupon`].

Comment: @gboffi I changed and ran the code, but it would return the error since I would have run this function through a DataFrame of 500 rows like `for period in periods:
   df[a], df[b], df[c] = \
                        zip(*df.apply(lambda df: optimalCoupon(df.recovery_rate,df.PD_rate, 1000), axis=1)`